# How to replace specific line or byte in a file with VS2013?

Tags: visual-studio-2013

I googled over the internet and couldn't find best answer.
What I am doing now is making a GUI, and that software can overwrite the information of the first line of the file that it opens. I tried to look at filestream etc. document in msdn but can not make it works.
How can I locate specific line such as first line or specify bytes count and offset I want to replace in the file?

Thanks

Comment: Please show the code that you have tried and describe how it didn't work

Comment: For example, following is the content of file that software gonna read                 :1500420611050B29052F050B11050B290535050B00B963
:08000000C243040003000000EC
:04000C001A4700008F
:100010001A4700001A4700001A4700001A4700005C                                    and I want to change some bytes in first line. Which function or class should I use? fileStream? StreamWriter? or something else. which function allows me to replace the content that I want? Thanks

Comment: Text files are *streams*, not random-access files.  You can only find line #n by reading n-1 lines.  And altering a line isn't possible since you can't create holes by making it shorter and you can't overwrite part of the next line by making it bigger.  Replacing file content is only possible when it is made up of records with a fixed size.  You have to rewrite the file.

Comment: Thanks Hans Passant. Make sense to me now. Lucky I just need to change some bytes in the first line, and won't change file size. So which function or class should I use? Because recored the whole file and replace the part I want then put back to the file sounds a little painful to me for just two byte changed. Thanks a lot